# Limits of factorial fraction

Tags: limits

How can I find the limit of x!/2^x when x ---> + infinite?

I figured out it's infinite but i don't know how to prove it using theorems.

Comment: Hint: look at the ratio of 2 consecutive terms.

Comment: Use the Ratio Test

Comment: @SkeletonBow The ratio test is not used to calculate the limit but used to check the divergence or convergence of series

Comment: @E.H.E if it were divergent, wouldn't the limit be infinity? Or could it also be a constant?

Comment: @SkeletonBow ok, but what about if it converges

Comment: @E.H.E ah, well the OP said that he figured it went to infinity, so I suggested that

Comment: @SkeletonBow I accept with you but sometime this test fails when the ratio equal to $1$, so we can not depend on it.

Comment: Indeed you are correct. Thank you.

Comment: @SkeletonBow you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$
\frac{2!}{2^2} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{2} = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
So, for $x > 2$ you have
$$
\frac{x!}{2^x} \geq \frac{1}{2} \frac{3^{x-2}}{2^{x-2}}.
$$
And
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3^n}{2^n}= \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint : The sequence $a_n=\frac{n!}{2^n}$ satisfies $a_0=1$ ,$\ a_{n+1}=a_n\cdot \frac{n+1}{2}\ $ for all $n\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

using Stirling's approximation
$$x!\sim {\sqrt {2\pi x}}\left({\frac {x}{e}}\right)^{x}.$$
so
$$\frac{x!}{2^x}={\sqrt {2\pi x}}\left({\frac {x}{2e}}\right)^{x}.$$
so the limit is $\infty$